# Using es7 functions with Babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I would like to include es7 functions in my project to start using fetch await asynchronous way in it.

I'm using gulp, browserify and babelify (7.2.0), reading some docs I saw that the way to say babelify to use es7 functions is including this line to the babelify transform:

```
optional: ['runtime', 'es7.asyncFunctions']
```

So that my whole gulp task is as follows:

```
gulp.task('js',function(){



var bundleStream = browserify({

    entries:[config.paths.mainJs],
    debug: true,

    transform: [babelify.configure({
        presets:["es2015","react"],
        optional: ['runtime', 'es7.asyncFunctions']
    })]


}).transform("browserify-shim")
    .bundle()
    .on('error',console.error.bind(console))




bundleStream
    .pipe(source('compiled.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
   // .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename('compiled.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/js'))


});
```

Unfortunetely I'm getting the following error running the task:

"Unknown option: base.optional while parsing file:"

Googling a bit I saw that babelify 7.x does use babel 6.0 and apparently this parameter optional does not exist anymore in babel 6.0.

I don't want to downgrade my babelify version to make this work but instead I would like to include es7 functions with the version 7 of babelify, does someone know how to do it?

Any help would be very appreciated as there is no much info about it out there

Just in case, please find also my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
"history": "^1.13.0",
"jquery": "^2.1.4",
"jquery-ui": "^1.10.4",
"jquery.easing": "^1.3.2",
"moment": "^2.10.2",
"react": "^0.14.3",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.28.1",
"react-dom": "^0.14.3",
"react-router": "^1.0.2",
"reflux": "^0.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
"babelify": "^7.2.0",
"browserify": "^9.0.8",
"browserify-shim": "^3.8.11",
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-open": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
"jest-cli": "^0.8.0",
"reactify": "^1.1.0",
"regenerator": "^0.8.42",
"streamify": "^0.2.5",
"uglify-js": "^2.4.20",
"vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
"vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
"watchify": "^3.1.2"
 },
"browser": {
"jquery": "src/main/webapp/js/libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js",
"x": "./vendor/x.js"
 },
"browserify": {
"transform": [
  "browserify-shim"
]
 },
 "browserify-shim": {
   "jquery": "$"
   }
```

Comment: is really ES7 or ES6 and added title by mistake, because your preset looks like presets:["es2015","react"],

Comment: How should it look like to use es7?

Comment: Your Title of your question is "Using es7 functions with Babel"

Comment: Sorry, not sure to understand, I'm pretty new here. I want to be able to use this code in my app: this.lang = await fetch( url )    .then( res => res.json() ). To do that I need to include es7 functions right, and we do that configuring it on babelify, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
optional: ['runtime', 'es7.asyncFunctions']
```

was how you configure Babel 5. You are using Babel 6, so it would be

```
plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-async-to-generator']
```

One thing to note is that configuring Babel via Babelify is not recommended. Instead, it is better to create an `.babelrc` file in the root of your application with JSON in it, e.g.

```
{
  presets:["es2015","react"],
  plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-async-to-generator']
}
```

and `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator`

Comment: Thanks, but no luck :(  Unexpected token (18:26)  it does not like the await word

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mark the function where I was using the await as 'async', but your configuration worked like a charme, Thank again!!!

Comment: By the way, I found that it is also works without the plugins if I add the stage-0 preset, what is the difference and what would you recommend to use?

Comment: Proposals have stages. `babel-preset-stage-0` enables all experimental functionality that is stage >= 0, which includes async functions and many other things. You can see the plugins for each stage by clicking on the presets on http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/